# TypeError: this.state.name.split is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am getting this error. I have three js files named App, Char,Validation.
Char component should convert a given text into single character and display them out. Validation is jsut to check length of character.

My error message:

```
  15 | 
  16 | 
  17 | render() {
> 18 |   const charList = this.state.name.split('').map((ch, index) => {
     | ^  19 |     return <Char 
  20 |       character={ch} 
  21 |       key={index} />;
```

My App.js code:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Validation from './Validation/Validation'
import Char from './Char/Char';
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: []
  };
  InputName = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value,
    });
  };
  
  
  render() {
    const charList = this.state.name.split('').map((ch, index) => {
      return <Char 
        character={ch} 
        key={index} />;
    });
    
    

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input onChange={this.InputName}type="text" placeholder="Input text" ></input>
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
        <Validation length={this.state.name.length} />
        {charList} 
          </div>
    
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default App;
```

My Char.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
const Char=(props)=>
{
  const style ={
    display:'inline-block',
    padding:'16px',
    margin:'16px',
    border:'1px solid black',
    textAlign:'center'

  };
  return(
  <p style={style}> {props.character} </p>)
};

export default Char
```

My validation.js Code:

```
import React from 'react';

const Validation =(props)=>{
    var ValidationMessage='Text is too short';
    if(props.length>=5)
    {
        ValidationMessage="Text is long";
    }
    return(
    <div className="ankit">
        {ValidationMessage}
    </div>
    )
}
export default Validation;
```

Comment: name is an array.... `name: []` Some reason you declared it as an array, you set it as a string.

Comment: `state = { name: [] };`: `this.state.name` isn't a string but an array, which doesn't have a function named `split` is its prototype.

Comment: I tried to add curly braces name:{} but it didnot work @sp00m

Comment: Well that is now an object, not a string....

Comment: `this.state.name.split('')`: this code seems to expect `this.state.name` to be a string though, doesn't it?

Comment: If you have time can you give me the solution??

Comment: declare it as an empty string.

Comment: `state = { name: "" };`? This should get rid of the error, but if you don't know whether you need an array, an object, or a string, then there might be other issues that will pop.

Comment: @sp00m you can clearly see how the OP is setting it....

Comment: I am follwing a tutorial and in that tutorial it works smooth in react 16 .0 but does not work in the latest one.

Comment: @sp00m I tried that but it showed the same problem as above